# $5-3|x-6|\leq 3x -7$

Tags: inequality, problem-solving, absolute-value

I have this inequation: 
$$5-3|x-6|\leq 3x -7$$

i solved this this way:

i said, for $x\geq6$ is the modulus positive, so I made 2 cases in which the modulus gives + or - :

1) for $x\geq6$ (positive):

$5-3x+6\leq 3x -7\\  
6x\geq30\\
x\geq5$

2) for $x<6$ (negative):

$5-3(-x+6)\le3x-7\\
-13\leq-7$

But i dont understand what those $x\geq6$ and $x\geq5$ say to me about $x$.

Comment: You distributed the $3$ incorrectly in the $x \ge 6$ case and dropped it entirely  in the $x < 6$ case.

Comment: @UmbertoP. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need $x\ge6$ and $x\ge5,$ so $x\ge$max$(6,5)=6$

Comment: i am supposed to get something $\geq6$, right? but i got $\geq5$, what does this tell me?

Comment: @doniyor, You have started with $x\ge6,$ and you found $x\ge5$ so $x\ge$max$(6,5)$  Had it been $x\ge6,x\ge7$ you needed to have $x\ge$ max$(6,7)=7$   Had it been $x\ge6,x\le5$ you would have had a null set

Comment: oh so it means, solution of inequation is some $x\geq6$ in my case, right?

Comment: @doniyor, yes as it satisfies $x\ge5$

Comment: perfect! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another way: rewrite the expression as $|x-6| \geq 4-x$ and denote $x-6=w$. After a bit of algebra the expression on the right can be written as $-w-2$, hence you need to solve
$$
|w| \geq -w-2
$$
Setting $w >0, w=0$ and $w<0$ it is easy to determine that the inequality holds iff $w \geq 0$. Now plug back in the expression for $w$ and you see that $x \geq 6$.